# textDocumentProxy insertText is not working in custom keyboard extension

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, ios-app-extension

I am trying to user textDocumentProxy to insert some texts from another view controller which presented from UIInputViewController. I am using NSNotificationCenter to post "SendText" notification, and the KeyboardViewController addObserver to this notification. The first time is working, but when I dismiss the view controller and present again. it's not working. The notification is received. Why it's working the first time, and when I present the ListViewController again, it's not working?

KeyboardViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(sendText:) name:kKeyboardSendTextNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)sendText:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    [self.textDocumentProxy insertText:notif.object];
}
```

ListViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Place *place = self.collections[indexPath.row];
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@? %@, %@", self.selectedType, place.name, place.mobileUrl];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kKeyboardSendTextNotification object:message];
}
```

Comment: Did you solve it? If yes, can you please share the way to do it as I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using notifications for this simple task? You can simply call the `insertText:` method as-is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Place *place = self.collections[indexPath.row];
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@? %@, %@", self.selectedType, place.name, place.mobileUrl];
    [self.textDocumentProxy insertText:message];
}
```

Comment: It's in another view controller, not in UIInputViewController. So I am using notification to do the job.

Comment: maybe you can register again after getting the notification

Comment: I am facing same problem, if you found any solution. please help me.